# Row-wise "ismember" without for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to perform a row-wise "ismember" in MATLAB in order to find out where, in `Set`, each element of `Input` is. 
Here is my work so far.

```
function lia = ismemberrow(Input, Set)
    lia = false(size(Input)); % Pre-assign the output lia
    for J = 1 : size(Input,1)
        % The J-th row of "lia" is the list of locations of the
        % elements of Input(J,:) in Set
        lia(J,:) = find(ismember(Set, Input(J,:)));
    end
end
```

For example, if the variables `Input` and `Set` are defined as follows

```
Input = [1 4; 
         4 2; 
         4 3; 
         2 4; 
         1 2; 
         3 2];
Set = [3 2 4 1];
```

The the output `lia` of `lia = ismemberrow(Input,Set)` will be:

```
lia = [4 3; 
       3 2; 
       3 1; 
       2 3; 
       4 2; 
       1 2];
```

My function works accurately so far, but this function is called many times in my project so I am thinking of that if I can reduce the for-loop so that it spends less time. May I have some opinions on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single call to [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) (no loop necessary) will give you what you want in the second output argument:

```
>> [~, lia] = ismember(Input, Set)

lia =

     4     3
     3     2
     3     1
     2     3
     4     2
     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inputs are positive integers you simply can use indexing

```
m(Set)=1:numel(Set);
result = m(Input)
```

If the range of input is large you can use sparse matrix:

```
s = sparse(Set,1,1:numel(Set));
result = s(Input)
```

Result:

```
   4   3
   3   2
   3   1
   2   3
   4   2
   1   2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `ismember` as in [@gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46200734/2586922). But here are some alternatives, just for the fun of it.

1. If the values in `Input` are guaranteed to be in `Set`:

   ```
   [ind, ~] = find(bsxfun(@eq, Set(:), Input(:).'));
   result = reshape(ind, size(Input));
   ```
2. If they are not guaranteed to be:

   ```
   [ind, val] = max(bsxfun(@eq, Set(:), permute(Input, [3 1 2])));
   result = permute(ind.*val, [2 3 1]);
   ```